# How to make a 3d surfaces in Java using TeeChart or JMathTools libraries?

Tags: java, teechart

I need to make some 3d surfaces in my Java application, and I have just found TeeChart and JMathTools libraries for it. But I can't find any examples how I can draw 3d surfaces programmatically. So, please, give me any example or suggest any free Java library for my task. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Surface/3D series in TeeChart work as I explained [here](http://www.teechart.net/support/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5312). Having that in mind, you can do something like this in TeeChart for Java:

```
Surface surface1 = new Surface(tChart1.getChart());

Random y = new Random();

for (int x= 0; x < 10; x++) {
    for (int z= 0; z < 10; z++) {
        surface1.add(x, y.nextDouble(), z);                
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I was ill. Please, tell me, are there any means to use functions instead of points? I mean that will be good to add functions for X,Y,Z.

Comment: @Денис Нагибин I'm sorry but I'm not sure about what do you mean here. Could you please elaborate on that? Thanks in advance.